# Retornar valor inserido após realizar o INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE tblUser (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    uuid VARCHAR(24) NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NULL
}
```

Estou inserindo um `uuid` randômico para que seja um identificador único diretamente dentro do meu banco de dados usando:

```
select substring(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 24
```

Essa query logo a cima me retorna um valor desta forma: `c4b912f99fc0c2e82526043c`

No PHP eu consigo retornar o ultimo `id` inserido no banco usando `mysql_insert_id()`, porém gostaria que no meu `INSERT` me retornasse o valor do`UUID` sem precisar criar um `SELECT`. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Acha que dá para aceitar a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Oi @bigown, apenas sua segunda frase da resposta respondeu minha pergunta, porém sem referência alguma. Mas claro que sei que você uma referência e tanto(não estou puxando saco - eu acho). A primeira frase vou aceitar como uma sugestão, importante, mas não como uma resposta. Percebi que de fato minha tentativa de gerar um UUID  - que não é uuid - é um tanto quanto falha, porque, como disseram e outra pergunta: "um raio sempre cai no mesmo lugar quando tem que cair". Obrigado pelo ensinamento, por mim e por muita gente aqui. Tenho muito a aprender e vou continuar persistindo nisso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como descobrir o que foi inserido no `INSERT` a não ser o último `ID`, tem que fazer o `SELECT` mesmo.

Comment: Ola bigown, o padrão UUID é: `6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29`. Desta forma, eu não queria que gerasse o o valor com o traço: `-`. Por este motivo estou fazendo desta forma. Caso eu use a função UUID, teria como fazer com que ele tenha apenas 24 caraters?

Comment: Mas isso é UUID, o que você está gerando não é. UUID tem 32 caracteres úteis e tem uma forma própria de geração. O que dá pra fazer é usar uma outra função junto para tirar os traços que acaba formando 36 caracteres no total. Existe uma forma mais curta, mas não acho adequada para o que está fazendo. Ainda que sequer entendo porque ter `ID` e `UUID`.

Comment: Bom, na verdade eu NÃO queria usar um valor sequencial para o identificador do usuário, e por esse motivo eu estou usando UUID (que não é uuid como você disse logo acima). Então queria que o identificador do usuário tivesse apenas 24 caracteres. Já vi que tem o UUID_SHORT() que possui 17 caracteres, porém é apenas numérico de acordo com a [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

Comment: Mas você está usando um sequencial. Eu não sei se usaria a versão reduzida para produzir algo único. Tem que decidir se quer ID único e universal ou alguma gambiarra, ou sequencial.

Comment: Minha tabela é outra, coloquei essa como exemplo, porque a estão que queria resolver era outra, no entanto chegamos a esse assunto. Mas já que quer me ajudar, eu estou **DECIDIDO** a ter um `ID` que seja, **não sequencial** com **24 caracteres** e **não somente numérico**. Você pode me ajudar? Acha que eu devo fazer outra pergunta ?

Comment: Talvez, acho que o que foi perguntado aqui foi respondido, já que sequer era sobre UUID :)

Comment: Okay. Me voy...